# Firebase Auth - How to use custom domain on the Phone OTP auth SMS?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am building a flutter app and using Firebase Auth, for the Phone sign in users receive an OTP SMS with a firebase domain with the verification code. How can I set it up to show my domain on the SMS.

> 123456 is your verification code for domain.firebaseapp.com

How can I set up the OTP to show *domain.com*, instead of, *domain.firebaseapp.com* ?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?

Answer (score 0):

Domain is nothing but the name of your project on Firebase. You will only recieve that format in **development mode only**.

Once, your app is live, you will get following result:

```
123456 is your verification code for <YOUR APP NAME ON PLAY/APP STORE>
```